# How to create a portable C/C++ program on linux using additional libraries?

Tags: c++, c, compilation, linker, portability

I need to create a portable linux program that uses a lot of additional libraries defined from yum (CentOS).

It is forbidden to install new packages on portable machines. There are no necessary libraries there.

How to assemble my program and all packages into a single folder through the gcc compiler? When I move this folder to another machine, my program should start and run successfully.

My program is ONLY allowed to use dynamic libraries. Static libraries are STRICTLY prohibited.

When trying to replace rpath with /usr/lib64/ with my libraries that are stored in my directory, after transferring to another machine, additional libraries give an error (glibc version conflict).

Comment: Well.. the more dynamic dependencies you have, the more complicated this gets. Is there a reason why static libraries are STRICTLY forbidden? Also are you asking for a portable binary that can be run on many different systems or a binary that is tailored for one specific remote system?

Comment: `LD_PRELOAD`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` should help ; `docker` is perhaps what you need. In all cases, `gcc` does not create package, it compiles as you said yourself.

Comment: @JakobStark Stark, yes, there are about 7 dependent libraries. Moreover, these libraries use each other, so I can't create a static library. I will move my program to a huge number of machines

Comment: If you can't install the dependencies but the necessary libraries are not there, then there's no way to accomplish your task.  You either remove the dependency (eg, compile with a static library) or you satisfy it (eg, install a new package).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a doomed project, for anything non-trivial.

Static libraries are not the issue though. Since they're just collections of .o files, you can [unpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9199806/how-can-i-extract-static-libs-containing-repeated-object-files) them. You can then state that you have just linked object files. Stupid rules give stupid results.

I am ignoring software licensing here, though, but that seems implied by the question. You don't need a license for libraries installed via yum, since YOU aren't shipping them. But you absolutely need licenses when you are shipping these libraries in one form or another as part of your product. And given the stupid rules, (L)GPL is likely out of the question, so you will need to obtain commercial licenses for all 7 libraries.